# Access overridden Chrome pages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, overriding

I [override a page](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/override.html) in Chrome.

Is there a way to open the old non-overridden page?

For example: override the history page with an own page, and open "old" history page as a new tab after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is absolutely no way opening the default page when you override it. If you wanted to do that, it would be best not to override it and dedicate that into its own page.

For example, make a [browser action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction) that once clicked, it will open your "history.html" page that you created. And from that page, you link it to the history page.

AFAIK That is the only way to have both pages present.